# Stylized content is shrunk in mobile browsers

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-browser

I’m working on making stylized responsive classes for buttons.  The text within the button should be the same size as the rest of the text on the page, and it works fine when resized on desktop, but when the pages are viewed on tablet/mobile, the size of the text in the button is much smaller than the normal text (its almost as though the `em` unit has changed sizes).  This has happened in all tested mobile browsers—safari, chrome, and default android browser—and no matter the HTML element the class is being applied to (`button`, `div`, `p`).
  I have another stylized class for a side menu that is experiencing the same text-shrinking effect (different class being applied to an `ul`).  Interestingly, the shrunken text of the menu is the same size of the shrunken buttons’ text, so whatever text size transformation is happening to one is happening to another.

Any ideas on how/why this may be?  Could it be related to the ‘auto-zoom’ of the mobile browser or something?  I’m fresh out of ideas, and would love to hear any thoughts on the matter

```
.blueButton, .greenButton{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #636363;
    border-radius: .3em;
    box-shadow: .25em .25em .4em 0px #636363;
}

.blueButton a:link, .greenButton a:link, .blueButton a:visited, .greenButton a:visited{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.blueButton:hover, .greenButton:hover{box-shadow: .25em .25em .4em 0px black;}
.blueButton:hover{ background: #0b3a74;}
.greenButton:hover{ background: #9ec83d;}

.blueButton{ /*gradients for different browsers- 1)Safari 2)Opera 3)Firefox 4)Standard*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #3c78cc , #0b3a74);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #3c78cc , #0b3a74);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #3c78cc , #0b3a74);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3c78cc , #0b3a74); 
}

.greenButton{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #caf170, #9ec83d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #caf170, #9ec83d);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #caf170, #9ec83d);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #caf170, #9ec83d);
}
```

Media queries:

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 1101px)
@media all and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1100px), (min-device-width: 1101px) and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px)
@media all and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 767px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 699px)
@media all and (max-device-width: 239px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-width: 239px)
```

Comment: Are you using media queries in your CSS?

Comment: yes--just added them to question

Comment: What about <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: Can you post a complete example (including the HTML) that shows the problem? I was going to say that buttons don't have the same font size as the surrounding text by definition, but then I saw that you were using divs as buttons.

Comment: Anyway, what happens if you remove the `font-weight:bold` from the CSS? And it wouldn't hurt to try adding `font-family:inherit` and `font-size:inherit`..

Comment: a little late- but thanks @jtorrescr, that solved pretty much all my problems!

Comment: Terrific, so lets add it has answer to close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in your `<head>` section.